# Python dictionary variable

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I would like to create a dictionary with keys that include variables name to make this code shorter

```
medic = {
'0.5 MG Comprim_': 0.5,
'1 MG Comprim_': 1,
'2 MG Comprim_': 2,
}
```

Something like

```
list = [0.5,1,2]
for x in list: 
    medic = {x + ' MG Comprim_': x}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about:

```
{str(x) + ' MG Comprim_' : x for x in [0.5, 1, 2]}
```

(Note this isn't a question on pandas / dataframe, you should remove those tags).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict` comprehension with casting numbers to `str`:

```
medic = {str(x) + ' MG Comprim_': x for x in [0.5,1,2]}
print (medic)
{'0.5 MG Comprim_': 0.5, '1 MG Comprim_': 1, '2 MG Comprim_': 2}
```